# Implementing a ‘Magic Sparks’ Animation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, particle-system

I’m currently working on a project using Jetpack Compose and Kotlin, and I’m trying to implement a ‘magic sparks’ animation. This animation should be triggered when the user performs a certain action or clicks on a button. However, I’m not sure where to start, as I understand that Jetpack Compose may not have a built-in particle system.

‘Magic sparks’ is a visual effect where a burst of small, light particles (the ‘sparks’) are emitted from a source, often accompanied by a bright glow.

I’m looking for guidance on how to approach this problem. Specifically, I would like to know:

Is there a way to create a particle system in Jetpack Compose?
If not, what are some alternative methods or libraries that I could use to achieve a similar effect?
For reference, I found a video that shows the type of animation I’m trying to implement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBFtnFLGMEw.

Comment: unfortunately your question is probably going to get closed as being either too broad, or for asking recommendations for libraries, this type of question doesn't really get answers on stack overflow unfortunately. hope you do find an answer eventually though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that is generally not bad for describing simple particle system effects.

https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti/tree/main

```
Party(
    speed = 0f,
    maxSpeed = 30f,
    damping = 0.9f,
    spread = 360,
    colors = listOf(0xfce18a, 0xff726d, 0xf4306d, 0xb48def),
    emitter = Emitter(duration = 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).max(100),
    position = Position.Relative(0.5, 0.3)
)
viewKonfetti.start(party)
```